# Chrome extension: Inject HTML in the DOM popup page from the background page

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm stuck now, in a background page, I would like use the .html() jQuery method on the popup.html DOM from background.html.

I found something with

```
var x = chrome.extension.getViews({type:"popup"});
```

What I have to do with x?

The popup may be closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

x will be an array of the windows you asked for, which in this case is the popup so should only be one.
Something like this should get you going....

```
var x = chrome.extension.getViews({type:"popup"});
if (x.length>0){
  $(x[0].document.body).html('I had chicken for lunch!');
}
```

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#method-getViews

Answer (score 1):

Some more info:-

x will be only those list of popup window which is currently open, otherwise it will not return. You can access all variable and methods which are declared at popup's windows level